# How to "get" from NodeJS with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I started an AngularJs App and to retrieve some data from database I'm using NodeJS (totally new to me), on the console of NodeJS it works and also typing the URL directly in the browser but when I try to get the information needed using `http.get()` in AngularJS using the same URL in the browser I get 404 not found.
I figured it would be a cors problem so I added

```
require('cors') in the nodeJS app and still doesn't work
```

Can anyone help me with that ? 
Am I right making separate apps for Angularjs in front-end and NodeJS in the Backend or should I assemble them in only one application ?

Thank you for your help

This is the AngularJS code:

```
$scope.keyLoad = function () {
    $http.get("localhost:8080/product")
         .success(function (response) {
             $scope.keys = response;
             console.log(response)
         })
};
$scope.keyLoad();
```

Comment: And your code is...?

Comment: unless your url is relative, you should specify the *full* url including protocol.  try `$http.get("http://localhost:8080/product")`

Comment: And read [this](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/), why `.then(...)` is preferred than `.success(...)`

Comment: @Claies — CORS has nothing to do with 403 errors. You get those when the server refuses to give the client the data because the client isn't authenticated. CORS is used to bypass the Same Origin Policy which is when the *browser* denies access to JavaScript from one site that is trying to read data from another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get 404 not found. I figured it would be a cors problem

If it says it is a 404 error then it is a 404 error and not a CORS problem.

Look at your code:

> ```
> $http.get("localhost:8080/product")
> ```

That URL is missing the scheme. It is a relative URL.

You are going to be requesting something like `http://example.com/myapp/localhost:8080/product`.

Put `http://` or `https://` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

For example:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Or

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: yes you are right , now it is printed in the console but can't use $scope.keys in an other place

Comment: what do you mean by in an other place?

Comment: I'm trying to use the result to draw a chart :   var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Homme', $scope.keys],
            ['Femme', 88]
        ]
    }
});

Comment: but $scope.keys is not recognised because it gives me an error : missing component

Comment: Where does this code goes to? Are they referring to the same `$scope`?

Comment: I'm not sure about this then.. but my guess is that this code is executed before $scope.keys is assigned with a value?

Comment: Actually even when I do : console.log($scope.keys) , it gets undefined in the browser

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works now . You were right , I was using different functions in the same controller so when I put them in the same function it worked